# Full calendar center title dont work it show right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to make the time show in the center. As it is written in the documentation, but shows from the right. I do not understand what the problem is.

```
            var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek',
                },
                height: 1000,
                // Calendar options
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
                editable: true,
                allDaySlot: false,
                firstDay: 1,
                displayEventTime: true,
                eventTextColor: 'black',
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',

                slotLabelFormat: "(H:mm)",
                timeFormat: 'h:mm',
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
```

[image]

Comment: create a fiddle

Comment: Sorry but the code you've shown does not reproduce this problem. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PomdgZm?editors=001 (using fullcalendar 3.10 and bootstrap 4). For us to help you, you'd need to provide the exact code and settings which would actually cause this to occur. I can only guess that you maybe somehow have some other CSS code in your page which is interfering with the fullcalendar / bootstrap CSS and overriding some rule(s) to mess up the header. Try using the element inspector in your browser to see what rules are being applied to those elements.